# Dynamic labelling of shapes

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating shapes within an For-loop and I want each shape having a different name. Therefore, the `Shape` in `Set Shape = ...` in each iteration should have Shape replaced by a dynamic variable.

If I place shapes via `Set Shape = w.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 10,10,10,10)` how can I have `Shape` (the name of the shape) be dynamic e.g. `Set Cells(1 + i, 1) = w.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 10,10,10,10)` ... so that each shape has a different name. I also tried `Shape.Name =` which does not seem to have the same effect as setting the name while creating the shape.

I assign a name for each shape which I create within the loop:
`Shape.Name = Cells(GanttStartRow + i, 1) & Cells(GanttStartRow + i, 2)`

I set the connector via
`Set conn = w.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorElbow, 1, 1, 1, 1) 
conn.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect D, 1
conn.ConnectorFormat.EndConnect WP, 1` ... but receive a "type mismatch" error.

Comment: Is `Cells()` in your question supposed to be an array of shapes? If so, that is an odd-choice of a name which overwrites a standard meaning of `Cells()` in VBA programming. If not, I have no idea what you are trying to do since you can't set a cell equal to a shape. Are you trying to put the name of the newly added shape into a cell?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming ws is the worksheet you are working with:

```
Dim s As Shape, i as integer
for i = 1 to 5
    Set s = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 50 + i * 120, 200, 100, 100)
    s.Name = "MyShapeName" & i
next i
```

You can later access the shapes by name:

```
For i = 1 To 5
    Set s = ws.Shapes("MyShapeName" & i)
    s.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255 - i * 50, i * 50)
    s.BackgroundStyle = i
Next i
```

However, an alternative is to loop over all shapes:

```
For Each s In ws.Shapes
    Dim i As Integer
    if left(s.Name, 1, 11) = "MyShapeName" then
        i = Val(Mid(s.Name, 12))
        s.Top = s.Top + i * 4
    end if
Next s
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried `Shape.Name = Cells(GanttStartRow + i, 1) & Cells(GanttStartRow + i, 2)`. However, later on when i want to connect my shapes I cannot refer to their names but I can refer to `Shape'